# Why is null stored as a string in localStorage?

Tags: javascript, null, local-storage

In the Chrome console I set `foo` to `null:`

```
localStorage.setItem("foo",null)
```

Then I test, whether it is null:

```
console.log(localStorage.getItem("foo")==null)
```

prints `false`.

Then I test, whether it is the string `"null"`:

```
console.log(localStorage.getItem("foo")=="null")
```

prints `true`.

I thought that `null` was a legitimate Javascript value. Storing it as the string `"null"` is very counter intuitive and caused a strange bug in an otherwise working program, when I cleared the localStorage in the browser manually.

Comment: You can only store Strings in `localStorage`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webstorage.html#the-storage-interface), `localstorage` uses *Storage* object interface

```
interface Storage {
  readonly attribute unsigned long length;
  DOMString? key(unsigned long index);
  getter DOMString? getItem(DOMString key);
  setter void setItem(DOMString key, DOMString value); //notice this line
  deleter void removeItem(DOMString key);
  void clear();
};
```

*setter* method translates to `setItem`, accepts only `DOMString`

As per [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString)

> DOMString is a UTF-16 String. As JavaScript already uses such strings,
>   DOMString is mapped directly to a String.
>
> Passing null to a method or parameter accepting a DOMString typically
>   stringifies to "null".

Answer (score 17):

Please see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

All values are stored as strings in local storage. You should stringify data before storing it and parse data after retrieving it:

```
localStorage.setItem("foo", JSON.stringify(null));
var value = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("foo"));
console.log(value === null);
```