# Why localStorage return a string value with case null and undefined

Tags: javascript, local-storage

When I save a `null/undefined` value into `localStorage`. The result I recieved when use `localStorage.getItem` will be a string (`"null" or "undefined"`)

```js
localStorage.setItem("item1", null)
localStorage.setItem("item2", undefined)

const item1 = localStorage.getItem("item1")
const item2 = localStorage.getItem("item2")

console.log(item1) // The result will be "null" not null
console.log(item2) // The result will be "undefined" not undefined
```

Anyone can explain for me with this case !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Js does Stringify it to local storage

```
storage.setItem(keyName, keyValue)
```

> keyName and KeyValue both are of type DOMString
>
> DOMString is a UTF-16 string. As JavaScript already uses such strings, DOMString is mapped directly to a String.
>
> Passing null to a method or parameter accepting a DOMString typically
>   stringifies to "null"

I saw we have 2 answers at the same time, so just to add his part from [mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem) and for [DOMString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString)

Comment: there is no need for asking clarification, I think this was what answer he/she was asking, I could be wrong though in the interpretation of the question.

Comment: this should goes to comment section or try to explain it a bit with some code example.

Comment: @jitender point taken, I have added all information required for the same, I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

> DOMString is a UTF-16 String. As JavaScript already uses such strings,
>   DOMString is mapped directly to a String.
>
> Passing null to a method or parameter accepting a DOMString typically
>   stringifies to "null".

Check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47150855/10971575

Answer (score 0):

Local storage can only save strings, so storing objects requires that they are turned into strings using JSON. stringify - you can't ask local storage to store an object directly because it'll store “[object Object]”, which isn't right at all!

```
// set new item which holds a numeric value
localStorage.setItem('number', 1);
// it would be a string value. localStorage only returns string value
console.log(typeof localStorage.getItem('number'));
```